# Does data-sveltekit-preload-data have an effect in {#each} blocks?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm dynamically creating my navbar with an `{#each}` block so as to not duplicate code, and I'm trying to make the page that each link goes to preload on hover.

I read these [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options) and came up with the following code:

```html
{#each navbarLinks as navbarLink}
    <li>
        <a href={navbarLink.href} data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
            {navbarLink.name}
        </a>
    </li>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without issue. You can check the network tab in the browser developer tools to confirm that the data is requested.